# SQL Server: Why would an ALTER TABLE to add nullable column run forever?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2014 Std Edition

We add columns all the time, and the ALTER TABLE commands return instantly.

E.g.

```
alter table [dbo].[Account] add ChildAccount nvarchar(100) NULL
GO
```

But at the moment, this alter table seems to run forever.

What would cause this?

Comment: Did you check for blocking ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some other session was blocking. A few min later, this command executed instantly.